# Is there a better way to use javascript to import of data from an external URL into mongo db

Tags: mongodb, import

The best I can come up with is to use the mongo shell "run" command to:

1. execute curl write to pull $someUrl to fs/tmp/myfile.ext
2. execute mongoimport to load fs/tmp/myfile.ext

I don't know the file system structure at compile time, so I am hoping the Gurus may know of a more direct way of loading data from a remote URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with any of the languages or drivers.

So if you use PHP + cURL + MongoDB, you can basically store the response right into MongoDB with all of the features of cURL.

The same should be true for most dynamic languages Python, Ruby, etc. If you use Node.js, the process should be quite similar. I only suggest the dynamic language for ease of scripting, but pretty much any of the [supported drivers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) should allow you to do this.

Frankly storing it in a file is probably unnecessary.

Comment: How do I store the response right into mongodb, and once I do, how then would I append process the response content to another collection. My current process is to do a scripting execution of the run command: mongoimport --file $file --headerline --type tsv. If I have the response content in the database can I do something similar? Note that the tsv file headers are variable.

Comment: What language and driver are you comfortable with? Generally, doing a WebRequest/cURL call + "save to database" is pretty straightforward.

Comment: The app is in java, but I have been building the mongodb interactivity in javascript and running with load/eval. I don't know how to do a " save to database" unless you start getting the driver and IO streams involved, it which case I would need to duplicate the mongoimport utility to add my extra needs, and I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: So you'll need the driver to get anything *out of* MongoDB, so I'm just assuming that you have the driver available in your Java code. `mongoimport` isn't really doing very much work, it's converting a CSV/TSV into an array/List of objects and then saving them. If you use a Java equivalent to cURL (`HttpURLConnection`?), you get your request back in memory (no file) and simply build an object from that request.

Comment: Is there some specific reason you need requests to be saved to a file?

Comment: Just b/c of the file size, the file sizes can be a few gigs. Some of the deployment scenarios have the mongodb server separated from the app server, which will require the use of the driver to carefully considerer network implications when invoking save commands. That and it seems like a lot more natural () doing the db processing logic in javascript vs. endless construction of java driver DBObject maps.

Comment: You are however correct that a lot of these concerns go away if one simply maps off that header line as mongoimport does, and then reads lines from a buffered reader from the url stream. However, these are the things I was trying to avoid by asking this question, but it it's the only way...

Comment: Recognize that a single document (record) in MongoDB can only be 16MB in size. This should handle most typical web pages, but if you plan to download a single 2GB file, you'll need to be aware of the limitations here. You may need to look at GridFS for such large files.

Comment: Note from the question that the intention is not store the downloaded file as a document, but to fetch the file and then process it with mongoimport, or a similar utility.

Comment: I took the advice and built a controller that captures a loads the file directly through the driver. I was worried about performance here, but initial tests show very similar stats.